# git diff - grep for specific substring

Tags: git, grep

I have over 100 changed files in my diff, I would like to get the file-names of the ones who contain a change which is has the substring "import"

Comment: @j6t That's not sufficient for reopening IMHO. No attempt == too broad, and there's a trivial answer which is accepted already.

Comment: @tripleee attempt to do what? I don't know the command. Do you want me to write git diff inside a code segment? `git diff` ? now is it ok?

Comment: At a modest minimum, tell us what you have searched for and which manual pages you studied before asking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a specific option `-G` for this purpose:

```
git diff -Gimport --name-only
```